# updateComponent - React

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, reactive-programming

I'm browsing through the react repository on Github and while I'm looking through lifecycle functions, I found this: `updateComponent: SpecPolicy.OVERRIDE_BASE`.

It shows the intended use case, but do you have any examples that have used this override? I've tried to fiddle around myself, but I'm only getting `null` returned unless I declare a variable inside my function scope.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"updateComponent" isn't really a part of a component's lifecycle methods. It will never be called even if you do provide an overload for it. It exists since it is used internally by ReactDOMComponent, and ReactCompositeComponent.

Also, it is unmentioned in the Component Spec and Lifecycle reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html